# wpf usercontrol

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I am using WPF UserControl and I have a grid so I want to generate a click event but it will not work so now what can I do.
thanks..

```
            <Border x:Name="frontWrapperWealthBudget" Width="260" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Border x:Name="frontHostWealthBudget" Width="260" Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="2">
                    <Border.BitmapEffect>
                    <BevelBitmapEffect BevelWidth="2" Relief="0.07" Smoothness="5"/>
                        </Border.BitmapEffect>

                    <Border.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF029CF0" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFD3EAF8" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>    
                    </Border.Background>
                    <Border.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.Loaded">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard Name="FrontWealthBudgetStoryBoard">
                                    <!-- Make the Viewport3D visible only for the duration of the rotation. -->
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                       Storyboard.TargetName="vp3DWealthBudget"
                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.1" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <!-- Make the background element visible. (It won't actually appear until it is
             faded in right at the end of the animation.) -->
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                       Storyboard.TargetName="backWrapperWealthBudget"
                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>


                                    <!-- Hide the foreground element. It will already be invisible by this time
             because we fade it out right at the start of the animation. However, until
             we set its Visibility to Hidden, it will still be visible to the mouse... -->
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                       Storyboard.TargetName="frontWrapperWealthBudget"
                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.05" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>


                                    <!-- Fade the front wrapper out. The Viewport3D is behind us, so it'll fade into
             view at this point. The reason for fading is to avoid a visible step as we
             switch from the real UI to the copy projected onto the 3D model. -->
                                    <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:0:0.05"
                       Storyboard.TargetName="frontWrapperWealthBudget"
                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />

                                    <!-- Fade the back wrapper in. Once the spin completes, we fade the real back UI
             in over the Viewport3D - using a fade to avoid a sudden jolt between the
             slightly fuzzy 3D look and the real UI. -->
                                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:1.05" Duration="0:0:0.05" To="1"
                       Storyboard.TargetName="backWrapperWealthBudget"
                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />

                                    <!-- 3D animation. Move the camera out slightly as we spin, so the model fits entirely
             within the field of view. Rotate the model 180 degrees. -->
                                    <Point3DAnimation To="0,0,1.1" From="0,0,0.5"
                       BeginTime="0:0:0.05" Duration="0:0:0.5" AutoReverse="True" DecelerationRatio="0.3"
                       Storyboard.TargetName="cameraWealthBudget"
                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(PerspectiveCamera.Position)" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="180" AccelerationRatio="0.3" DecelerationRatio="0.3"
                       BeginTime="0:0:0.05" Duration="0:0:1"
                       Storyboard.TargetName="rotateWealthBudget"
                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Border.Triggers>
                    <GroupBox  FontFamily="Bold" FontSize="16" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Style="{DynamicResource GroupBoxStyle2}" Width="260" Height="150">
                        <GroupBox.Header>
                            <StackPanel Name="back1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="-50,0,0,-20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="186.697">
                                <Image Margin="10,3,0,0" Width="35" Height="35" Source="images/home 1.png" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                <Label Content="Wealth Manager" Margin="5,3,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Height="30" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </GroupBox.Header>

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label1}" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Bold" FontSize="14" x:Name="lbl1WealthBudget" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource AlertsSrc}}" Margin="0,25,0,0"/>
                            <TextBlock Margin="0,25,0,0" Text="{Binding Label2}" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Bold" FontSize="14" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" x:Name="lbl2WealthBudget" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource AlertsSrc}}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </GroupBox>
                </Border>
            </Border>
```

Comment: You can post some code/XAML for a good start.

Comment: You will have to be a little clearer here. "have a grid and __thus__ want a click event" ??

Comment: Good for the code. Can you explain in a bit more detail how do you "want to generate a click event"? Do you wan to handle it instead perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I want to generate a click event but it will not work"

what was that mean?

You want to do something if clicked on grid or so meting else in window(object) which is host your control?